# Iterate through object keys and values which are array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object of key and values(array of objects)

```
 Obj:{ 
    key1: [{desc:'aaa', pos:0}, {desc:'bbb', pos:1}],
    key2: [{desc:'ccc', pos:0}, {desc:'ggg', pos:1}],
    key3: [{desc:'ddd', pos:0}, {desc:'jjj', pos:1}],
    key4: [{desc:'eee', pos:0}, {desc:'kkk', pos:1}]
  }
```

From the above...I need to get an array of objects for each key in the object. So,I need to get the desc property of a position 0 and assign to text1 below. The text2 and text 3 will be hardcoded.

```
data = [
  {
    text1: 'aaa',
    text2: 'name2',
    text3: '29/112/2017',
  },
  {
    text1: 'ccc',
    text2: 'name2',
    text3: '29/12/2017',
  },
 {
    text1: 'ddd',
    text2: 'name2',
    text3: '29/12/2017',
  },
 {
    text1: 'eee',
    text2: 'name2',
    text3: '29/12/2017',
  },

]
```

Tried the following but doesn't work...

```
 var values = Object.values(obj); - would give me an array of array of objects

 values.map((item, index) => {
    item.map((i, x) => {

    if(i.pos == 0)
        {
           return(
               { 
                  text1: i.desc,
                  text2: 'name2'
                  text3: '29/12/2017'

               }
               )
         }
})
```

How would I get a structure like "data" array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Barmar, there is no need to have a separate array because map returns an array. I have fixed your code so you can have an idea of how you can dynamically push data into an array:

```
data = []
var values = Object.values(Obj)
values.map ((item , index)=>{
    item.map((i , x)=>{
        if(i.pos == 0){
            data.push({ 
                  "text1": i.desc,
                  "text2": 'name2',
                  "text3": '29/12/2017'

             })
        }
    })
})
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `item.map`. All you care about is `item[0]`, so just index it directly.

```js
var obj = { 
    key1: [{desc:'aaa', pos:0}, {desc:'bbb', pos:1}],
    key2: [{desc:'ccc', pos:0}, {desc:'ggg', pos:1}],
    key3: [{desc:'ddd', pos:0}, {desc:'jjj', pos:1}],
    key4: [{desc:'eee', pos:0}, {desc:'kkk', pos:1}]
  };
  
var values = Object.values(obj);

var result = values.map(item => ({
  text1: item[0].desc,
  text2: 'name2',
  text3: '29/12/2017'
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar and Taimoor!!! I'll go with Taimoor's answer as its checking for position(pos)...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = { 
    key1: [{desc:'aaa', pos:0}, {desc:'bbb', pos:1}],
    key2: [{desc:'ccc', pos:0}, {desc:'ggg', pos:1}],
    key3: [{desc:'ddd', pos:0}, {desc:'jjj', pos:1}],
    key4: [{desc:'eee', pos:0}, {desc:'kkk', pos:1}]
  };
 
 var data = [];
  
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, value){
 var dict = {};
 dict.text1 = obj[key][0].desc;
 dict.text2 = 'name2';
 dict.text3 = '29/112/2017'
 data.push(dict);
});
console.log(data);
```